# How to get state of hook?

Tags: c, winapi, hook

I quote [win api reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The hook procedure should process a message in less time than the data entry specified in the LowLevelHooksTimeout value in the following registry key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
>
> The value is in milliseconds. If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the next hook. However, on Windows 7 and later, the hook is silently removed without being called. There is no way for the application to know whether the hook is removed.

I did understand that there are no function to inspect hook chain or get state, but. does a workaround exist?

I discover that my hook after some events does not receive event anymore and I've think about that.

EDIT 1:
In my code I set the hook with windows set hook ex
I get notified so the hook is well configured
I put a message loop
I unhook the hook and return

the hook procedure code :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int code, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param){
  KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbd_hook = NULL;
  char tmp[0xFF] = {0};
  char tmp2[0xFF] = {0};

  if ( code == HC_ACTION )
  if( w_param == WM_SYSKEYDOWN || w_param == WM_KEYDOWN)
  {
    kbd_hook = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)l_param;
    GetKeyNameText((kbd_hook->scanCode << 16)  , tmp2, 0xFF);
    CharToOem(tmp2, tmp);
    printf("tmp: %s\n",tmp);
  }
  return CallNextHookEx(key_handle, code, w_param, l_param);
};
```

When i type on my keyboard Num.lock and pause key the hook doesn't receive noifications

Comment: The most elegant way is probably to fetch the timeout and be aware that if your operation exceeds it when it completes your hook has been killed by the system as documented.

Comment: If your hook is too slow you may consider offloading the real work to another thread. In the hook function just notify the thread by setting an event, for instance. Then the hook function will be able to always return quickly.

Comment: I doesn't think it is too slow I use only one printf call and return callnexthookex. @zett42

Comment: I've seen in my register with regedit.exe. I have not this key in my registry. @AlexK.

Comment: Another possibility is that another hook has been installed in front of yours and is blocking input from reaching yours. In that case, the only option is to either reinstall your hook so it is put in front again, or don't use a hook at all, use the Raw Input API instead

Comment: I'm sure no hook is installed because it's stop from receiving when a special combo key is pressed (only) and I have not launch any app and I have kill all app except winlogon.exe explorer.exe cmd.exe and when I press control-C to kill my program I see that cmd get the key. (I've already seen your comment in another thread and checked for that.) I think my gcc (mingw 5.3.0) version doesn't have the good header to use raw input. @RemyLebeau can raw input get keystroke when run in background? could data race occur in this code? because the two key that make the hook bug have the same scanCode.